# How to avoid repeating the string array in @Secured spring security

Tags: spring-security

To secure my REST API's I am using @Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_SUPERADMIN", ...some more} etc. 
But I have to repeat this on every API manually. I found https://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1398 for Groovy but couldn't find about how to do it in JAVA. 
From my understanding I feel that I have to write a custom annotation (e.g. @MySecured("OnlyAdmins") ) which will work as a sort of Pre-Processor and will get replaced with the above @Secured annotation. 
However I wanted to know if there is any better way to achieve the same? Also it would be really helpful if somebody could point me to some ready made custom annotation source code for achieving this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this, create a parent role ALL_ADMINS, and setup spring security hierarchical roles, see the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/authz-arch.html) for further details.

creating a role voter with the configured role hierarchy:

```
<bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleHierarchyVoter">
    <constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy" />
</bean>
<bean id="roleHierarchy"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <property name="hierarchy">
        <value>
            ROLE_ALL_ADMINS > ROLE_ADMIN
            ROLE_ALL_ADMINS > ROLE_SUPERADMIN
            ...
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then applying it to a custom access decision manager:

```
<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <beans:property name="decisionVoters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean ref="roleVoter" />
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

and last configuring the custom access decision manager to be used by `@Secured`:

```
<global-method-security access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    ...
</global-method-security>
```